# Current mode buck modeling

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, simulation, buck, pspice

I am following this document [Loop response consideration in PCM](http://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/an/slvae09a/slvae09a.pdf). Here I am implementing fig 5 schematic in page 9. From equation 1 to 22 got me some of the hidden values of the schematic which I have inserted. 
Some of them are `gm * Rcomp =9.54` `Rcomp * Ccomp = 26.5u` `Rcomp * Co_EA= 1.06u` from equation 21 and 22.
Vslope = 0.476V from equation 21 and I am assuming Vslope = T* Ri * V /L From here I got Ri = 1.88 
which I inserted it as gain of the sense amplifier. Fsw= 1.1MHz.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Plot]

I am getting D = 39% for 5V output I am supposed to obtain 41.6%
Is my calculation incorrect? Here am trying to understand the control loop and dependency of signals on each other and its theoretical equations which are necessary for transient modelling of PCM buck.
Is there any better way to understand modeling steps/parameters (equations) to be followed while transient modeling of current mode buck?